# Est-ce que les tournures « se tromper en » et « commettre des erreurs en » sont idiomatiques?

Tags: constructions, formulation-idiomatique, formulation, reformulation

1- Cet utilisateur est maladroit, il se trompe en transcrivant des formules.

2- Cet utilisateur est maladroit, il commet des erreurs en reportant des formules.

Que ces tours soient boiteux ou non, vous pouvez m’en proposer d’autres; je veux élargir l’horizon fort peu développé de mes connaissance en matière de formulation…

Je me répète, mais si je suis ici, c’est pour rendre mon expression la plus claire, la plus concise et la plus élégante qu’il me sera possible. Auparavant j’écrivais sans me soucier le moins du monde de la qualité de mon français, seules les idées m’importaient. Mes écrits étaient lourds et alambiqués car mon lexique était fort peu enrichi, les idées auxquelles je cherchais à donner corps appelaient beaucoup de mots. Maintenant j’ai placé la qualité de mon français en tête de mes priorités, surpassant de ce fait la place dédiée aux idées et à l’imagination (enfant j’avais l’esprit beaucoup plus fertile). Je trouve que la conciliation « haut standard en français écrit » et « idées débordantes » est difficile, c’est comme si les efforts mis dans la première catégorie nuisaient aux efforts mis dans la deuxième dans mon cas… Il faut comprendre que la qualité étouffe les idées… Je ne vais pas vous ennuyer plus longuement avec ma digression. Je vous invite à interpréter ce paragraphe-ci comme étant la motivation de ma question.

Comment: Peut-on savoir pourquoi vous dites utilisateur là?

Comment: « Rendre corps » est vieux (19ème siècle), rare aujourd'hui. On dit surtout « faire prendre corps » et « donner corps » ([ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=prendre+corps%2Cdonner+corps%2Crendre+corps&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=30&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cprendre%20corps%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cdonner%20corps%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Crendre%20corps%3B%2Cc0)).//On ne trouve « rendre corps ni dans le TLFi, ni dans le dictionnaire de l'Ac., ni dans le Littré. // TLFi : Loc. verbales fig.− [Le suj. désigne une chose abstr.] Prendre corps. (1/2)

Comment: ♦ Devenir perceptible, sensible, comme matériel; se matérialiser. − [Le compl. d'obj. désigne une chose abstraite] Donner (un/du) corps à qqc.
♦ Donner (un) corps à qqc. Lui donner forme, précision, consistance; lui donner de la réalité, le matérialiser; le réaliser, le concrétiser. Donner corps à l'espoir, à l'ambition, à une œuvre; donner un corps à une idée, à une théorie, à des rêves.//Voir le TLFi pour plus de détails. (2/2)

Comment: Il y a des problèmes de grammaire dans la construction « la plus claire, la plus concise et la plus élégante que cela me le sera possible. » ; « que » doit être le pronom relatif ; l'antécédent doit être « expression » ; donc c'est le pronom object et il faut un verbe transitif, ce que « être » n'est pas. Donc il faut une construction comme par exemple « que je puisse concevoir », « qu'il me soit possible d'élaborer », etc. Autrement, il y a le choix alternatif du  superlatif relatif qui implique une « comparaison des degrés possible d'une même chose » :  (1/2)

Comment: « le plus claire, le plus concise et le plus élégante possible. » (Observations sur le superlatif relatif. a) Dans l'usage soigné, l'article du superlatif relatif d'un adjectif reste invariable quand il y a comparaison entre les différents degrés d'une qualité, quand l'être ou l'objet sont comparés avec eux-mêmes, spécialement dans des moments ou des lieux distincts. ♦ C'est au milieu de ses enfants qu'une mère est LE plus heureuse (= heureuse
au plus haut degré).  (2/2)

Comment: Voir  cet [article](http://alafortunedumot.blogs.lavoixdunord.fr/archive/2019/02/03/faut-il-dire-qu-elle-est-%C2%A0la%C2%A0plus%C2%A0belle%C2%A0-%C2%A0ou%C2%A0-%C2%A0le%C2%A0plus%C2%A0belle-15897.html) pour des commentaires supplémentaires.

Comment: Et si j’écrivais plutôt: « La plus claire, la plus concise et la plus élégante qu’il me sera possible. » , la phrase serait-elle correcte? Ici je me suis inspiré de « Venez le plus tôt qu’il vous sera possible », https://www.dictionnaire-academie.fr/article/A9P3593

Comment: S’agirait-il d’une expression figée?

Comment: On doit entendre la phrase concernée comme « Venez le plus tôt qu’il vous sera possible [de venir], l’ellipse permettant d’éviter la répétition du verbe « venir ».

Comment: Je cherche à mettre la phrase que tu as mise en évidence et celle que j’ai tirée de l’Académie française en parallèle.

Comment: c’est pour rendre mon expression la plus claire, la plus concise et la plus élégante qu’il me sera possible. Je dirais: c'est pour avoir une réproduction **aussi claire que concise et élégante**. La personne reproduit les textes en les tapant, n'est-ce pas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Les deux termes "se tromper" et "commettre des erreurs", dans le domaine de l'écriture, sont des synonymes exacts, et de même pour "transcrire" et "reporter".
Ce n'est pas du tout le cas dans certaines situations de la vie courante pour les deux premiers (« Il a commis des erreurs lorsqu'il était jeune. »//« <s>Il s'est trompé lorsqu'il était jeune.</s> »).

> ([TLFi](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/transcrire)) **A. −1. transcrire** Reproduire très exactement, par l'écriture, ce qui a déjà été écrit. Synon. copier, enregistrer, recopier.

> ([TLFi](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/reporter)) **β) reporter** Transcrire sur une autre page ou sur un autre document, un autre support. Reporter des corrections.

Le [gérondif](https://bescherelle.ca/gerondif/) a une fonction de complément circonstanciel. Il s’emploie pour exprimer :

> 1 **Le temps, ou plus précisément une action simultanée, concomitante à l’action principale**
> 2 **La cause**
> 3 **La supposition**
> 4 **la condition**
> 5 **la manière**
> 6 **l’opposition**
> 7 **la concession**

Le [TLFi](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/en) en cite un de plus, le moyen, et dans l'ensemble, bien moins.

> C.− [En introduit une forme en -ant pour former un gérondif fonctionnant comme un compl. circ.]
> − **[de moyen]** C'est en forgeant qu'on devient forgeron.
> − **[de temps]** Écoute, dit Dubreuilh, tout en le soignant, essaie donc de le cuisiner.
> − **[de manière]**

Si on considère ces deux phrases, il est apparent que seulement convient la fonction de CC de temps, ou, plus précisément—comme le mentionne « 1 » ci-dessus—CC de simultanéité. On se rend donc compte « techniquement » que la relation entre l'erreur et la transcription n'est pas plus spécifique qu'une notion de coexistence, même si, bien sûr, l'esprit extrapole (plus ou moins aisément) pour conclure que l'erreur se trouve *dans* la transcription. Cette construction moins qu'idéale qu'une analyse grammaticale met en évidence transparait aussi dans la lecture du lecteur averti tout simplement parce que dans le français d'un  style plus strict cette pratique ne se trouve pas ; les bons auteurs tendront à l'éviter ; le « bon » lecteur, lui, n'a pas développé d'habitude, il n'identifie pas une construction solide (même s'il comprend).
La relation est donc plutôt une relation de lieu *figuré*. Cependant, ce n'est pas tout. Cette relation n'est pas la seule possibilité ; cette relation de lieu figuré, qui est la plus plausible, implique que l'erreur se trouve dans  une  duplication qui n'est pas exacte, c'est à dire une duplication où des symboles ont été changés, omis ou ajoutés ; on peut aussi interpréter la relation comme étant la *manière* : dans ce cas l'erreur consiste dans le fait de dupliquer des formules, c'est à dire qu'au lieu de dupliquer des formules, cette personne devrait faire autre chose, ou, tout au moins, elle ne devrait pas dupliquer de formules.
Tout cela se traduit par une impression que  cette construction est  bonne à  tout faire, un peu comme le verbe « faire », dont certains enseignants déconseillent une utilisation trop fréquente, des termes plus spécifiques étant la marque d'un meilleur style selon eux (ce que je pense aussi).

Bien que des phrases de ce type soient acceptées par de nombreuses personnes, on peut trouver préférable de les reformuler.

On peut noter que des constructions de ce type  avec "quand/lorsque" sont assez courantes et équivalentes, mais elles ne paraissent pas résulter en beaucoup d'amélioration

*phrase prépositionnelle (participe présent → substantif correspondant)*

- Cet utilisateur est maladroit, il se trompe *dans la transcription* de formules.

*D'autres alternatives*

- Cet utilisateur révèle une certaine maladresse manifestée par des erreurs de transcription [de/dans des] formules.
- Cet utilisateur fait preuve de maladresse en cela qu'il ne peut pas transcrire de formules sans introduire d'erreurs.
- Cet utilisateur est enclin à être maladroit, ses transcriptions de formules contiennent des erreurs.

Answer (score 5):

Les deux phrases sont idiomatiques et grammaticalement correctes.

Il ne s'agit pas vraiment de tournures spécifiques ***se tromper en*** / ***commettre des erreurs en*** mais de verbes/groupes verbaux (*se trompe* / *commet des erreurs*) accompagnés de gérondifs (*en* + participe présent) qui auraient pu être placés avant le sujet :

1- Cet utilisateur est maladroit. En transcrivant des formules, il se trompe.

2- Cet utilisateur est maladroit. En reportant des formules, il commet des erreurs.

Il n'est cependant pas facile de se prononcer sur la justesse du vocabulaire sans connaître le contexte et le sens précis attendu.

<s>***Utilisateur*** qualifie une personne qui utilise quelque chose, un service par exemple alors qu'ici, il semble plutôt s'agir d'un élève faisant des devoirs.</s>

***Maladroit*** s'applique plus à un manque d'habileté manuelle (une personne maladroite peut faire des tâches). Il peut s'agir de problèmes de concentration, mais on peut, c'est vrai, être maladroit avec un clavier.

En postulant que tu veuilles dire la même chose avec les verbes ***transcrire*** et ***reporter***, le plus simple serait d'utiliser un verbe plus courant et compatible avec eux comme *recopier*.

***Il se trompe*** est plus concis que ***il commet des erreurs*** mais est plus fort et ambigu. On pourrait comprendre qu'il se trompe pour chacun des formules à transcrire, voire qu'il se trompe complètement car il devait en fait faire autre chose que transcrire les formules. Le mieux est de rajouter *souvent* ou *parfois* pour donner une idée de la proportion des transcriptions erronées.

Tout ça donne par exemple :

> Cet utilisateur manque de concentration. Il se trompe souvent en recopiant les formules.

Comment: Dans le cas concerné, il s’agit d’une personne qui tape des formules sur une plateforme de questions et de réponses, elle les copie à partir d’un autre site internet. Comme « taper » est une activité manuelle, j’ai pensé que « maladroit » pouvait bien traduire l’idée d’une personne manquant de dextérité. Mais je l’admets, le contexte était fort peu développé

Comment: Ok, dans ce cas, *utilisateur* convenait bien.

Comment: @Jean-LouFrenette … En changeant de registre, (autodérision nécessaire) : — « J'suis nul comme mec, j'sais mêm'pas faire un copier/coller ! » — « J'suis naze total, j'arrive à m'tromper en copiant-collant ! »

Comment: @Personne  Je les adopte! Merci Personne.

Comment: @Jean-LouFrenette : « Il faut comprendre que la qualité étouffe les idées », à part les crétin·es formaté·es pour grimper haut dans l'échelle sociale des “sachants”, laissez vivre votre intuition créative, vos délires artistiques … et vous découvrirez que la qualité dépend des idées policées par la pensée.