# Pourquoi la phrase ci-après n’est-elle pas correcte?

Tags: constructions, formulation-idiomatique, formulation, reformulation

Première: Je veux rendre mon expression la plus claire, la plus concise et la plus élégante qu’il me sera possible.

Pourtant on dit bien (deuxième) « Venez le plus tôt qu’il vous sera possible »

Source: http://www.dictionnaire-academie.fr/article/A9P3593

Je cherche à mettre les deux phrases concernées en parallèle pour comprendre ce qui cloche avec la première.

Merci.

Comment: Votre nouvelle question m'a fait penser à une de vos  questions précédentes qui en explique la raison. Je m'aperçois qu'il y plusieurs de vos commentaires qui sont sans réponse ; je dois m'en excuser, je n'ai rien  pu répliquer du fait que les notifications ne me sont pas parvenues.

Comment: deux phrases? Lesquelles? A mon avis, on dit: venir le plus tôt possible mais on ne dirait pas: rendre une expression la plus claire.

Comment: @Lambie J’ai mis les informations à jour!

Comment: @LPH La deuxième phrase dans les détails a la même construction que celle en question (première), pourtant elle est donnée en exemple dans un dictionnaire qui se proclame « la référence » en matière de bon usage.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Je ne peux que répéter l'explication que j'ai faite dans l'espace commentaire de votre question précédente ([question](https://french.stackexchange.com/q/47048/17649)).
« Que » doit être le pronom relatif ; si « que » était la conjonction la proposition serait soit objet soit complément circonstanciel ; ce n'est certainement pas un objet ; serait-ce un complément circonstanciel ? Non plus, l'idée exprimée est celle d'agir de façon maximale sur l'expression pour accomplir le résultat « l'expression la plus… », où, en d'autre mots, d'agir sur  « que ». Donc c'est un pronom relatif. Le problème est maintenant le verbe « être »: en aucune sorte de manière peut-il avoir un complément d'objet,  ce n'est pas un verbe d'action ; une construction comme par exemple « que je puisse concevoir », « qu'il me soit possible d'élaborer »,  etc., pallie à ce problème.

On trouve bien « le plus tôt que » ([ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=le+plus+t%C3%B4t+que&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=30&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cle%20plus%20t%C3%B4t%20que%3B%2Cc0#t1%3B%2Cle%20plus%20t%C3%B4t%20que%3B%2Cc0), [livres](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22le%20plus%20t%C3%B4t%20que%22&tbm=bks&lr=lang_fr)), mais un examen de cette information montre que c'est une forme en fort déclin, et il ne serait pas surprenant que la raison soit l'appréhension par les utilisateurs éduqués du français que ce n'est pas une forme bien définie, qu'elle est basée sur une logique plutôt floue. Ce déclin vers la désuétude est encore plus vrai pour la variante orthographique « le plus tôt qu' » ([ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=le+plus+t%C3%B4t+qu%27&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=30&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cle%20plus%20t%C3%B4t%20qu%20%27%3B%2Cc0#t1%3B%2Cle%20plus%20t%C3%B4t%20qu%20%27%3B%2Cc0)).

Il semblerait donc, comme vous le supposez, que ce soit une forme plus ou moins figée, à prendre en tant qu'idiomatisme.

Comment: Réponse excellente et détaillée. Merci beaucoup LPH!

Answer (score 2):

La phrase :

> Je veux rendre mon expression la plus claire, la plus concise et la plus élégante qu’il me sera possible.

est tout à fait compréhensible et pour moi correcte, même si la formule finale est un peu désuète.

On peut trouver des phrases similaires comme :

> C'est ce que je vais tâcher de faire le plus exactement & le plus succinctement qu'il me sera possible ! *Bibliothèque choisie de médecine*, 1763

> En attendant, je vais le conduire à la perfection la plus grande qu'il me sera possible. *Archives de l'art français, Volume 48*, 1911

et donc aussi dans le dictionnaire de l'Académie :

> Venez le plus tôt qu’il vous sera possible.

Cette forme sous entend simplement *[...] qu'il me sera possible **de la rendre/de faire/de la conduire/de venir*** mais ces parties ne sont pas exprimées puisque ce serait une répétition.

On peut tenter de simplifier la phrase de la question comme ceci :

> Je veux rendre mon expression la plus claire, la plus concise et la plus élégante que possible.

mais on trouvera plus souvent :

> Je veux rendre mon expression aussi claire, concise et élégante que possible.

ou :

> Je veux rendre mon expression la plus claire, la plus concise et la plus élégante possible.

Une recherche élargie montre que ce type de formulation se retrouve dans quantité de documents, y compris des meilleurs auteurs et même un ouvrage pédagogique sur l'art d'écrire :

> Oh bien, faites donc, pour le reste, du mieux qu'il vous sera possible. *L'impromptu de Versailles*, Molière, 1663.

> [...] et, si vous l'abordez, demeurez avec elle le moins qu'il vous sera possible. *La princesse d'élide*, Molière, 1664.

> Elles auront pour objet de donner plus de précision et de clarté aux choses : elles vous forceront à ne rien laisser dans le vague, à imaginer le détail **le plus particulier, le plus individuel qu'il vous sera possible**. *Conseils sur l'art décrire. Principes de composition et de style à l'usage des élèves des lycées, des collèges et de l'enseignement primaire supérieur*, Gustave Lanson, 1916.

Considérer que cette forme est incorrecte est donc difficilement défendable.